# How AWS Region-wide RIs are applied since it now affects all the instance of the same family?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've just read that AWS updated their Region-Wide RIs (only for Linux instances), to apply them to the whole instance family (before it was only matching the exact instance type). This allows for instance a "t2.large" RI to match two "t2.medium".

So I was wondering how AWS was matching each RIs with the instances, for example two possibilities that comes to my mind:

- Match the RIs with the bigger "factor" first. If there is more Reserved Capacity than instances, the "little" RIs remain unused
- Try to match "full" RIs as much as possible, and so limit the number of "partial" RIs

Moreover, if an instance matches the exact type of one of these RI, is it prioritary compared to the other instance of the family?

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-instance-size-flexibility-for-ec2-reserved-instances/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

If you have a smaller number of instances actually running than what you reserved (e.g. reserve a t2.medium, but have only 1 × t2.micro and 1 × t2.small running -- 3/4 of the reservation) then you still pay for the entire reservation and the unused capacity is lost (it doesn't roll over, or anything).

If you have a larger number of instances actually running than you reserved, (e.g. reserve a t2.medium, but have 2 × t2.small or 1 × t2.micro running -- 5/4 of the reservation) then you're either going to be billed additionally for 1 × t2.micro **or** 0.5 × t2.small (the doc you cited mentions that if an instance overflows the boundary, you pay a pro-rated charge for the additional capacity), which is already very close to the same amount -- $0.012/hr vs. $0.0125/hr in us-east-1 -- but according to the EC2 FAQ:

> **Q: Can I control which instances are billed at the discounted rate?**
>
> No. AWS automatically optimizes which instances are charged at the discounted rate to ensure you always pay the lowest amount.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/

So, whichever algorithm arrives at that price should be the one that is applied.

Note also that you used the phrase "reserved capacity," which is not what regional reserved instances do.  There is no actual, physical capacity reserved for you.  That only applies to reserved instances purchased with availability-zone+instance-type granularity, and these aren't subject to the flexible equivalency mapping described here.

With reserved intances, it has always been the case there is no concept of which specific instances are reserved at any moment in time.  The purchased quanity of machine hours is used to zero-out the charges from an equivalent amount of machine hours that you actually used.  This change simply expands the purchased hours so that they cover hours on other types of instances within the same class, not just the same type, as was the case before, and now allows the purchased hours to also reduce billing for an instance that fits only partially within the purchased instance hours.

---

Terminology:

For the purposes above, I'm considering `t` as an instance family (a label not relevant to reserved instances), `t2` as an instance class, and `t2.large` as an instance type, which I believe to be the correct designations, although "class" and "type" are sometimes interchangeably used to refer to the specific type of instance.

EC2 has a separate concept of a *reservation* that is unrelated to reserved instances, and in fact unrelated to actually reserving anything.  A reservation, in this other sense, is a logical grouping of instances launched via a single API request and using the same specs and AMI.  Every instance is launched inside a reservation, but when multiple instances are launched together, they share a reservation and each instance has a *launch index* number, giving it a logical position within the group.  This is not often actually used for anything, but it's a value the code running on an instance can inspect, so that -- for example -- in a cluster of instances launched together from the same AMI, the software running on the instances might modify its behavior based on a role it infers from its launch index.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response! In fact I was asking that because we internally need to re-match the RIs with the instances. We decided to use the origami reports instead, which already detail which RI cover an instance.